# How to retrieve name from XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to make a XPATH which returns the name of the products whose count is higher than 5.

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding ="UTF -8"?>
<list>
   <product>
      <name>A</name>
      <parts>
         <part count="3">X3</part>
         <part count="1">Y2</part>
         <part count="2">Z6</part >
      </parts>
   </product>
   <product>
      <name>B</name>
      <parts>
         <part count="1">G3</part>
         <part count="2">Y6</part>
      </parts>
   </product>
   <product>
      <name>C</name>
      <parts>
         <part count="6">K9</part >
         <part count="3">Y6</part>
      </parts>
   </product>
</list>
```

My attempt was:

```
//name/following-sibling::parts/part[@count>5]

More readable version
/list/product/parts/part[@count>5]
```

The XPATH I made returns `<part count="6">K9</part >` which is partially correct, but it doesn't return the name of the product.
At this point I'm not even sure if I'm supposed to return the actual name (C in this case) and if it's even possible to do so or if my method is correct. Any input would be welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
//product[parts/part/@count > 5]/name
```

or

```
//part[@count > 5]/ancestor::product/name
```

or

```
//name[../parts/part/@count > 5]
```

There are many ways to skin a cat, as they say.

Comment: That is correct, ty! I didnt exacly know how to go back on the tree

Comment: Depending on the approach, "going back" isn't even necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using the following xpath

```
/list/product/parts/part[@count>5]/../../name
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The `..` is not a "backreference". It's simply a shorthand for `parent::*`.